# Calculating matrix determinants based on another's.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$A = \begin {bmatrix}  a & b & c \\ 4 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end {bmatrix} \ \ , \ \ \left| \ A \ \right| = 3$$

Knowing only this, how does someone calculate the determinant of things like

$$B =\begin{bmatrix} 2a & 2b & 2c \\ 4 & 4 & 4\\ 2 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \text {or} \ \ \ C = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ 3a + 4 & 3b & 3c+2\\ a+1 & b+1 & c+1\end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \text{?}$$

I don't need the answer, I just have no idea how to do it.

Comment: There are "three rules" (really, they're theorems one would prove): 1) a "swap" between two rows or columns  "flips" the determinant's sign; 2) multiplying a row or column by a constant multiplies the determinant by that constant; 3) adding a multiple of a row (or column) to another row (or column) has _no effect_ on the determinant.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: So basically, I use row operations to go from $A$ to $B$, keeping track of the ones I used, and then, apply all the changes to $A$'s determinant to get $B$'s, right?

Comment: Yes, keep track of the changes.  The ones that involve adding some multiple of one row to another row do nothing, though.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: I prefer concepts to tricks and rules ;)

Comment: They weren't intended as "tricks": they are applications of determinant theorems.  I was being a bit glib since this was just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** use multilinearity of the determinant with respect to lines (or columns) and antisymetry.

details:
$$\det B =\det
\begin{bmatrix} 2a & 2b & 2c \\ 4 & 4 & 4\\ 2 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
= 2\times 4\times \frac 12
\det
\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ 1 & 1 & 1\\ 4 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}
= -4\det A = -12
\\
\det C =\det
\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ 3a + 4 & 3b & 3c+2\\ a+1 & b+1 & c+1\end{bmatrix}
= \det
\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ 4 & 0 & 2\\ 1 &1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
=\det A = 3
$$

Comment: For $C$, there were no changes because the only two operations you did were $r_1+r_2$ and then $3r_1+r_2$ and they don't modify the determinant right?

Comment: the changes $r_i \to r_i + yr_j, j\neq i, y\in \Bbb C $ do not change the determinant.